# 3D Tic Tac Toe with Minimax & Alpha-beta pruning picks sub-optimal moves

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm trying to implement Minimax with Alpha-beta pruning for a game of 3D Tic Tac Toe. However, it appears the algorithm chooses sub optimal paths.

For example, you can win simply by running straight through the middle of the cube, or across a single board. The AI seems to pick cells that would be optimal the *next* turn, not the current turn.

I've tried recreating and playing with the heuristic I return for the algorithm but I haven't made much progress. Regardless of the ply it appears to have the same problem.

The code is [here](https://github.com/Battleroid/3ttt/blob/master/ttt.py).

The relevant portions are `computers_move` and `think_ahead` (and the '2' variants, those are just me experimenting with a slightly alternate approach).

I'm hoping it might be something simple I overlooked, but as far as I can tell I am not sure what the issue is. If anyone can shed light on the problem I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
def computers_move2(self):
    best_score = -1000
    best_move = None
    h = None
    win = False

    for move in self.allowed_moves:
        self.move(move, self.ai)
        if self.complete:
            win = True
            break
        else:
            h = self.think_ahead2(self.human, -1000, 1000)
        self.depth_count = 0
        if h >= best_score:
            best_score = h
            best_move = move
            self.undo_move(move)
        else:
            self.undo_move(move)

    if not win:
        self.move(best_move, self.ai)
    self.human_turn = True

def think_ahead2(self, player, a, b):
    if self.depth_count <= self.difficulty:
        self.depth_count += 1
        if player == self.ai:
            h = None
            for move in self.allowed_moves:
                self.move(move, player)
                if self.complete:
                    self.undo_move(move)
                    return 1000
                else:
                    h = self.think_ahead2(self.human, a, b)
                    if h > a:
                        a = h
                        self.undo_move(move)
                    else:
                        self.undo_move(move)
                if a >= b:
                    break
            return a
        else:
            h = None
            for move in self.allowed_moves:
                self.move(move, player)
                if self.complete:
                    self.undo_move(move)
                    return -1000
                else:
                    h = self.think_ahead2(self.ai, a, b)
                    if h < b:
                        b = h
                        self.undo_move(move)
                    else:
                        self.undo_move(move)
                if a >= b:
                    break
            return b
    else:
        diff = self.check_available(self.ai) - self.check_available(self.human)
        return diff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my algorithm appears to work fine. The problem was caused by my helper functions `move` and `undo_move`. In addition the root problem was my set of allowed moves.

I noticed while it was exploring the tree the number of moves diminished heavily in the outermost loop in `computer_plays`. During even the first sweep the number of allowed moves per pair of turns by the computer and human player would reduce from say 27 total, to 20, then 10, and eventually 5.

Turns out temporarily tested moves were not being replaced. So I swapped the set for a standard list and sorted the list after each move/undo and the resolved my problems completely.